# Modifying font size in quotation and chapter headings

Tags: fontsize, books

Using the standard `book` document class, I'd like to modify the size of the text output when inserting a `quotation` (with `\begin{quotation}`) to appear smaller than the standard font; same question but applied to `\chapter` and `\section` headings.
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\AtBeginEnvironment{quotation}{\smaller}
\chapterfont{\large}
\sectionfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\chapter{title of chapter}
\section{section title}
 normal sized text
\begin{quotation}
 quotation text
\end{quotation}
normal text 
\end{document}
```

I have set the fontsize of the `quotation` environment to be relatively 'smaller' than the size of the text. Additionally, I have used the `sectsty` package to influence the font sizes of `chapter` and `section` headings.

The image compares the output of the above MWE with (left) and without (right) the font size adjustments.

[image]

Comment: This is the solution I used!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `quoting` package and it eponymous environment: writing in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{font={itshape,footnotesize}}
```

will make all `quoting` environments be typeset in italic, footnote size.

For chapters and sections font size, you can use `titlesec` with option `[bib]`, `[medium]`, `[small]` or `[tiny]`.The default is `[big]`, `[tiny]` sets the font size to text size, `[medium]` and `[small]` are intermediate sizes.